# removing a row from gridview dynamically at runtime

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grid

I have created a gridview which adds a remove button through item template. I wish to know how do u remove the row from grid view dynamically depending upon the button he clicks ?

```
protected void RemoveBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)clickedButton.Parent.Parent;
        int rowID = Convert.ToInt16(row.RowIndex);

        GridView1.DeleteRow(rowID);
    }



<asp:GridView ID= "GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnRowDeleting="RowDeletingEvent">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove Items">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button id="RemoveBtn"  runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="RemoveBtn_OnClick"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GridView.RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx).

> The RowCommand event is raised when a
>   button is clicked in the GridView
>   control. This enables you to provide
>   an event-handling method that performs
>   a custom routine whenever this event
>   occurs.
>
> Buttons within a GridView control can
>   also invoke some of the built-in
>   functionality of the control. To
>   perform one of these operations, set
>   the CommandName property of a button
>   to one of the values in the following
>   table.
>
> ```
> CommandName Value
> "Delete" - Deletes the current record. Raises the RowDeleting and RowDeleted events.
> ```